# Running individual tests with Jhipster in STS

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to write some new unit tests for a jHipster application generated w/ [jHipster version 3.3.0][1], I've imported my project into [STS (w/ Gradle)][2], and it runs fine if I select "Run As Spring Boot App" or "Debug As Spring Boot App", and running `./gradlew test` seems to run all the tests, however, I'd like to run just individual tests with JUnit Integration tests [as stated][3]:

> Those tests can be run directly in your IDE, by right-clicking on each
>   test class, or by running mvn clean test (or ./gradlew test if you run
>   Gradle).

When I right-click on my test, and use 'Run As Junit Test', the entire app appears to run (though it mentions *No Profile Selected using Default*).

Here is my simple test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyAPP.class)
@IntegrationTest
@Transactional
public class UtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testGenerateRandomName(){
        Assert.assertNotEquals(null,RandomUtil.generatedRandomWordString());
    }
}
```

Advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared your test as an integration test using MyApp.class as spring context, so your test starts the full application, this is the expected behavior.

If you want to run a simple unit test, remove all your annotations.